# Does proliferate give my creatures +1/+1 counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I'm using proliferate cards in my white/green deck. If I use the ability proliferate on, let's say, [Pollenbright Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPollenbright%20Druid%5d), does it allow me to give a +1/+1 to my druid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reminder text of proliferate is:

> Choose any number of permanents and/or players, then give each another counter of each kind already there

So if your creatures have +1/+1 counters already on them, you can add more with proliferate.
If they have no counters, proliferate will not add any.

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to the question as asked is usually no. You will not be able to use Pollenbright Druid's proliferate trigger to give +1/+1 counters to Pollenbright Druid herself, because what proliferate does is add more of a counter that players and/or permanents already have - not add new types of counters to those that do not already have those types of counters.

If somehow Pollenbright Druid entered with a +1/+1 counter, say from [Chorus of the Conclave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChorus%20of%20the%20Conclave%5d) or more commonly seen recently (though not for WG like your deck) from [Grumgully, the Generous](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrumgully%2c%20the%20Generous%5d) or [Rhythm of the Wild](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRhythm%20of%20the%20Wild%5d), she will already have a +1/+1 counter when she entered and thus that counter can be proliferated by her ability.

Proliferate, as defined by the comprehensive rules:

> > **[701.26a](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Proliferate)** To proliferate means to choose any number of permanents and/or players that have a counter, then give each one additional counter of each kind that permanent or player already has.

Pollenbright's other mode, "Put a +1/+1 counter on target creature" can however be used to put a +1/+1 counter on her, but in a deck that uses counters usually proliferate will be the more valuable choice, since it lets you add counters to everything that already has one.

Answer (score -3):

If - with the expression "my druid" - you mean the same [Pollenbright Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPollenbright%20Druid%5d), then the answer to your question is:
- No, since proliferate ability allows you to add counters on a given creature only if at least one counter is already present on the given creature.

Comment: I think "my druid" is not enough to make someone understand we're talking about Pollenbright Druid...even it is well asked,expression is important!